# logstash 5.0 custom output plugin fails leading to load error

Tags: plugins, output, logstash

If I attempt to start logstash 5.0 with a custom output plugin (Ensured that I ve configured path.plugins correctly in the logstash.yml ) fails with the following error -

**Trying to load the XXXXX output plugin resulted in this error: LoadError**

I feel that for some reasons the register method in the plugin is not getting invoked. I debugged and see that the exception is being thrown at:
**registry.rb:69:in `lookup'**

which means that the plugin registration indeed did not happen. And hence there is no entry for *path,klass* for my custom o/p plugin.
This was working all fine until logstash 2.2.1.

I browsed through the documentation for breaking changes, and followed whatever is being asked for. However, still I see this error.

- Please note:

I am **not** using plugin-install. I am trying to use the output plugin in a standalone fashion as a java based custom plugin.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Yogesh

Comment: You have to call `logstash-plugin install ...` in order to install your plugin and be able to use it in your pipeline. What do you mean by "using the plugin in a standalone fashion"?

Comment: Until logstash 2.2.1 I have been using my custom plugin with command line plugin path specification. Without calling logstash-plugin install.
So while running logstash, my command line would have --pluginpath PATH.
Where PATH is the path to my custom plugin.

Comment: Further to clarify - I am talking about the custom plugin scenario as described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html

See topic ---> Advanced: Using --path.plugins

Comment: Can you show the full command line you're using?

Comment: For Logstash 5.0 - In logstash.yml, I have configured -

 path.plugins: [ "MY_CUSTOM_PLUGIN_DIR_ABSOLUTE_PATH" ]

Ofcourse, I am following the recommended directory structure for plugins. And as I mentioned, I had gone through the available docs to ensure that I am not overlooking anything.
Before this I attempted -p in the command line. But it failed. And I see the recommendation to use the logstash.yml instead. I am referring to: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6074

Comment: Any comments Val?
Isnt there any way in Logstash 5.0 to work with custom plugins?

Comment: Can you tell where you plugin is and what path you're using in the `path.plugins` setting?

Comment: In the logstash.yml file:

 path.plugins: [ "/home/yogesh/Logstash/logstash-5.0.0/logstash-scala" ]

and the directory under which my plugin files (.jar and .rb files) are is:
/home/yogesh/Logstash/logstash-5.0.0/logstash-scala/logstash/outputs

Comment: That's strange, indeed.